# Add a custom class to awating comments

Tags: comments

So not sure if i have missed something but awaiting comments dont have a own class, so is there a way to add in a simple way a custom class to comments that are awaiting moderation so that I can style there comments with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to add a custom `.wpse-comment-awaiting-moderation` comment class through the [`comment_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_class/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'comment_class', 'wpse_259326_comment_classes', 10, 5 );

function wpse_259326_comment_classes ( $classes, $class, $comment_ID, $comment, $post_id )
{
    if( 'unapproved' === wp_get_comment_status( $comment ) && is_array( $classes ) )
        $classes[] = 'wpse-comment-awaiting-moderation';

    return $classes;
}
```

where we used that [`wp_get_comment_status( $comment )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_comment_status/) returns `'unapproved'` for *unappproved* comments.

Comment: this outputs a error: Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\xxxxxx\wp-includes\comment-template.php on line 430 i am using wp_list_comments() to outpu the comments

Comment: strange, I don't see any obvious problems with the snippet.  I just tested this on a default theme without an error and it worked there. @user759235

Comment: Sounds like your get_comment_class() is returning a string instead of an array? Do you have another filters in place? What PHP are you using?

Comment: php  5.3.0 with wp 4.7.2 and no other files or code

Comment: Maybe it's the anonymous function here that's not supported by your PHP (your PHP version is old!).  Ttry to rewrite it with a normal function instead and see if that works @user759235

Comment: no even when i change this the same error is there

Comment: I rewrote it without an anonymous function. Try to remove parts of it to see what line is causing the problem on your setup and check what's inside $classes. .

Comment: okay not sure why, but it now works....thanks!!!!