# get_comment_meta() for a filter hook in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I'm trying to add a CSS class to a comment and everything seems to work if the comment id was hard coded in. However it's not working because I don't know how to get the comment id and then from there, get the comment meta stored in the database.

in `wp_commentmeta` I have the following data:

```
meta_id
1

comment_id
10

meta_key
score

meta_value
0.25
```

I then have this code using a filter hook to add the class to the list of comment classes. However, this is in a standalone plugin in the /wp-content/plugins folder and I need to loop through all the comments for that post.

```
function add_comments_class( $classes, $class, $comment_ID, $comment, $post_id ) {

    $meta_data = get_comment_meta( $comment_ID, 'score', true );

    $meta_data = round((float)$meta_data * 100 );

    $classes[] = $meta_data;

    return $classes;

} add_filter( 'comment_class', 'add_comments_class' );
```

I've looked at [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta) but that doesn't seem to identify how to get the ID when viewing a post etc.

The variables in the function were taken from [this answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/259336/111400) although it doesn't explain why those specific variables are used or where they are from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you need to use the `$comment` variable within your function which should then allow you to search the database properly.

Using the [`global variable scope`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) you can select the main comment variable.

```
global $comment;
```

And to get the comment id, you can use:

```
global $comment;
echo $comment->comment_ID;
```

Comment: I think it would be better to reduce the direct use of globals, specially when the comment ID is available within the callback.

Comment: How could I use it within the callback? I couldn't find any info on this. I might have been searching for the wrong thing though.

Comment: Did you try the changes I suggested regarding the priority and number of input numbers in the `add_filter()` part?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I checked another plugin to see how someone else did it and they have done it the same way.

Comment: it works well for me, if you echo the `$comment_ID` within it, what do you get when you view the HTML source? How does your current code snippet look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to add the **priority** and **number** of input arguments, so change

```
add_filter( 'comment_class', 'add_comments_class' );
```

to

```
add_filter( 'comment_class', 'add_comments_class', 10, 5 );
```

where 10 is the priority and 5 is the number of input arguments passed on to your callback.

*You can see that I specify the priority and number input arguments for the  callback in my previous answer that you linked to.*

Also consider using a prefix to your callbacks, like `wpse_260620_add_comments_class()`, or use a namespace, to avoid a possible name collision.